# Writing Hive table from Spark specifying CSV as the format

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having an issue writing a Hive table from Spark. The following code works just fine; I can write the table (which defaults to the Parquet format) and read it back in Hive:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable("db.table")

hive> describe table;
OK
val           string
Time taken: 0.021 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

However, if I specify the format should be csv:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').format('csv').saveAsTable("db.table")
```

then I can save the table, but Hive doesn't recognize the schema:

```
hive> describe table;
OK
col                     array<string>           from deserializer
Time taken: 0.02 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

It's also worth noting that I can create a Hive table manually and then `insertInto` it:

```
spark.sql("create table db.table(val string)")
df.select('val').write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("db.table")
```

Doing so, Hive seems to recognize the schema. But that's clunky and I can't figure a way to automate the schema string anyway.

Comment: What is the schema of the Dataframe? Are there commas in the data?

Comment: What is the output of **df.printSchema**?

Comment: Why _"clunky"_? You want to create a Hive-compliant dataset, so it seems reasonable to use a Hive-compliant method to create it. And for the record, it's even worse with Parquet, because by default Spark does not use the same binary encoding as Hive... and the way to override that default is not documented cf. [SPARK-20937]

Comment: @cricket_007 and Ankush Singh: The schema and data are trivial and I've tried various. Even a DataFrame with a single column that is an integer will fail to write a schema that Hive can read (using the csv format).

Comment: @samsonScharfrichter I say "clunky" because you have to write a hive-compliant schema string. When using `saveAsTable` with the default format, you don't have to do that. I hadn't run into the binary encoding issues with Parquet. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

That is because `Hive SerDe` do not support `csv` by default.

If you insist on using `csv` format, creating table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(a string, b string, ...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "'",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)  
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

And insert data through `df.write.insertInto`

For more info:

> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde

Comment: Thanks for the info. I mentioned that this strategy works, but it's clunky because you have to generate the schema string (`a string, b string, ...`). Is this the only solution for Spark to write a table that both Spark and Hive can read?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a table with text format and trying to insert CSV data into it, which may run in to problems. So as suggested in the answer by Zhang Tong, create the hive table using hive OpenCSVSerde.

After that, if you are more comfortable with Hive query language than dataframes, you can try this.

```
df.registerTempTable("temp")
spark.sql("insert overwrite db.table select * from temp")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow. The default for `saveAsTable` is Parquet and that works just fine. Surely the Hive SerDe doesn't natively support Parquet, either. Right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I actually mean is that, create the hive table with whatever the format is needed. Then just write the data in the dataframe to hive table. In this way, you don't need to bother about the format while writing. I provided the basic alternative code snippet to write from dataframe to hive table, without worrying about the format.

Hive supports Parquet SerDe natively. Please refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Parquet

Comment: so is it fair to say that Hive supports Parquet natively but not CSV?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because HiveSerde is different for csv than what is used by Spark. Hive by default use TEXTFORMAT and the delimiter has to be specified while creating the table.

One Option is to use the insertInto API instead of **saveAsTable** while writing from spark. While using **insertInto**, Spark writes the contents of the Dataframe to the specified table. But it requires the schema of the dataframe to be same as the schema of the table. Position of the columns is important here as it ignores the column names.

`Seq((5, 6)).toDF("a", "b").write.insertInto("t1")`

Comment: The issue is creating the Hive table in the first place. I agree that if it already exists, you can use `insertInto`. But I don't know of an easy way to generate the table from within Spark if it doesn't already exist.